# Error: Unknown host 'No such host is known (proxy)'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I'm try to connect Firebase's realtime database and keep getting this error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Update your project level `build.gradle` to latest version - it worked for me

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: @Luong Nguyen Viet Khoa K16_HL  .... Let me know does this worked for you or not ?